# How to avoid double compilation and testing with cobertura:check?

Tags: java, maven-2, cobertura

I'm using `maven-cobertura-plugin` in order to calculate code coverage in my project. As I understand, this plugin starts a new/forked build cycle in order to compile and test the code base. When it's done the plugin calculates code coverage. As I understand, this is the only approach the plugin can use, and it's fine for me.

The problem is that before `cobertura` plugin my code base is compiled and tested already. Thus, I'm experiencing duplicated compilation and testing. Is it possible to avoid compilation and testing *before* `cobertura`? Or maybe there is some other workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to avoid compilation and testing before cobertura? Or maybe there is some other workaround?

There are several issues about this (see [MCOBERTURA-83](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOBERTURA-83), [MCOBERTURA-76](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOBERTURA-76)) but AFAIK, there is no perfect workaround (due to the way the life cycle is constructed - things might be improved in Maven 3).

The only one I'm aware of (works with CI servers) would be to run:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

and then

```
mvn cobertura:check
```

Instead of binding `cobertura:check` on the build lifecycle.

Note that compiling twice shouldn't be an issue as all classes should be up to date.

Comment: this is really helpful thanks a lot.. but in my case cobertura printing some unwanted exception logs, is there any way to stop them?

Comment: Be careful if this is in a CI environment. What I found is that when tests fail during the cobertura execution, they don't cause the build to fail. For this reason, my CI server does `mvn clean install cobertura:cobertura`, effectively running all the tests twice. Unfortunately, looking at the activity in the plugin's JIRA, I have little hope that this will ever be resolved. :(

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, cobertura needs to do bytecode weaving on your code to be able to work.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to work around that was to instrument the byte code as part of my build (by binding the `cobertura:instrument` goal to the `verify` phase and also bind the `default-test` execution from `maven-surefire-plugin` to the `verify` phase so it doesn't get executed as part of the `test` phase on every `cobertura` goal execution.